# Can I lock screen after move mouse in lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen

I lock my computer. Accidentally the mouse moved. Then the lock menu was shown by the computer. Can I lock it without input the password and lock again?

Comment: What do you mean "can you lock it without password"? If you had locked your desktop, and your mouse moved afterwards, then it is still locked. There's no need for you to lock it again.

Comment: @msPeachy I mean can i lock the screen without: unlock the screen then lock it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Can we assume you are using **12.04** or **12.10**...*

---

Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to remove 'Unlock' dialog.

---

Yes, there is a shortcut to **lock screen** (*if unlocked*).  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, to immediately lock the screen.

Comment: **@Eliah** I should remember to use kbd-meta when adding comment.

Answer (score 1):

A shortcut to turn the screen off again does not exist. You should wait for a few minutes or you unlock and lock again.